# Gmail API historyId if there are no messages during users.watch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am running into an issue where I am saving the `historyId` from [users.watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch#LabelFilterAction). I am doing a null check to make sure that `historyId` is returned which it passes, but somewhere my downstream interprets it as a falsey value.

What is `historyId` if we do not have any messages in our mailbox? Could it be `""`, `"0"`, or anything else? The documentation doesn't a default response.